# Can I rollback after calling oracle procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, rollback

I have a `procedure` that calls 2 inner `procedures`, I want to `rollback` the procedures call if a condition is true, is this possible?

This pseudo demonstrate what I want to do:

```
Create or Replace procedure Main

   Call procedure_1();
   Call procedure_2();

   IF X = true THEN
      ROLLBACK;
   END IF;

END Procedure Main;
```

Comment: Look up transactions in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#i7105

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this [`Using SAVEPOINT With ROLLBACK`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/savepoint_statement.htm)

```
Create or Replace procedure Main

   SAVEPOINT sp_1;
   Call procedure_1();       
   Call procedure_2();

   IF X = true THEN
      ROLLBACK TO sp_1;
   END IF;

END Procedure Main;
```

Note:

If your stored procedure have any `DDL statements` like `create\alter\drop\truncate etc..` then the `savepoint` will be invalid as DDL statements issue `commit` before and after the statement.

You can rollback to a `savepoint` defined in the current transaction, you cannot rollback to the `savepoint` after issuing `DDL statements/Commit`.

Comment: I got this error :  savepoint 'sp_1' never established in this session or is invalid

Comment: If your stored procedure have any `DDL statements` like `create\alter\drop\truncate etc..` then the savepoint will be invalid as `DDL` statements issue `commit` before and after the statement.

Comment: no I dont have any DDL statments, all I have is select,insert and update statment only.

Comment: do you have any commit statements in the procedure

Comment: Yes , I found commit in the the inner procedure, I deleted it and it worked, Thank you